# Video from internal network served to an externally visible web page

Tags: video, apache2, streaming

I am being asked if it's possible to take video from an internal IP camera and serve it to our external website like a live-feed camera.

My initial thought is that it would have to be done through some kind of video proxy and have it pointed to from a virtual host on our web server, then configure a link to that page from our existing CMS.

I'm looking for either a way to do this, or ideas on how better to create such a page and serve the video stream.

The server is Ubuntu 11.04, the CMS is WebGUI, the web server is Apache2. I can edit for more information if requested. Am I on the right track with using some kind of proxy internally to serve an internal-IP video to external viewers? Is there a video proxy that can do this for Linux, preferably in the repos?

EDIT - It's a VB-C500 camera.

EDIT 2 - I can apparently view a "live stream" with some variant of /-wvhttp-01-/video.cgi?v=mp4:320x240 but I'm not sure how to get this to proxy into our web server on the external address.

Comment: Can you provide any information about the camera or its software?  Sometimes there are camera or software specific solutions provided by the company that made the camera.

Comment: Edited into question.